# How to create parent and childrens by giving two or more columns as a grouping in any SELECT, but efficiently?

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose I have data similar to the one below, but the complete table has: auto-increment, measurement values, dates, foreign keys, descriptive texts. In the example I created, it has only auto-increment, a value, a date and two foreign keys that represent a device and a customer. The same equipment may have more than one customer and a customer may have more than one equipment. I want to create a history by grouping these two foreign keys. A new column would be used to identify the parent's id, like `id_parent`.
Example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_stackoverflow`;
CREATE TABLE `test_stackoverflow`  (
  `auto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` VARCHAR(255),
  `fk_1` INT,
  `fk_2` INT,
  `valor` DOUBLE,
  `dt_analysis` DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (`auto`) USING BTREE
);
INSERT INTO `test_stackoverflow` VALUES (1, 'Material 1', 1, 1, 1.300, '2019-04-02 12:04:40');
INSERT INTO `test_stackoverflow` VALUES (2, 'Material 2', 1, 2, 1.500, '2019-04-02 12:05:59');
INSERT INTO `test_stackoverflow` VALUES (3, 'Material 3', 2, 1, 1.400, '2020-04-02 12:06:34');
INSERT INTO `test_stackoverflow` VALUES (4, 'Material 4', 1, 1, 1.700, '2020-04-02 12:06:52');
INSERT INTO `test_stackoverflow` VALUES (5, 'Material 5', 1, 2, 1.800, '2020-04-02 12:07:22');
```

I got something with

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT      
        auto, auto as id_parent, description, fk_1, fk_2, valor, dt_analysis
    FROM test_stackoverflow
    ORDER BY dt_analysis DESC
)
    SELECT
        T1.auto, CTE.id_parent, T1.description,T1.fk_1,T1.fk_2, T1.valor, T1.dt_analysis
    FROM test_stackoverflow AS T1
        INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.fk_1 = T1.fk_1 AND CTE.fk_2 = T1.fk_2
    WHERE T1.auto <= CTE.id_parent
    ORDER BY id_parent, auto;
```

It works:

```
+------+-----------+--------------+------+------+-------+---------------------+
| auto | id_parent | description  | fk_1 | fk_2 | valor | dt_analysis         |
+------+-----------+--------------+------+------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 |         1 | Material 1   |    1 |    1 | 1.300 | 2019-04-02 12:04:40 |
|    2 |         2 | Material 2   |    1 |    2 | 1.500 | 2019-04-02 12:05:59 |
|    3 |         3 | Material 3   |    2 |    1 | 1.400 | 2020-04-02 12:06:34 |
|    1 |         4 | Material 1   |    1 |    1 | 1.300 | 2019-04-02 12:04:40 |
|    4 |         4 | Material 4   |    1 |    1 | 1.700 | 2020-04-02 12:06:52 |
|    2 |         5 | Material 2   |    1 |    2 | 1.500 | 2019-04-02 12:05:59 |
|    5 |         5 | Material 5   |    1 |    2 | 1.800 | 2020-04-02 12:07:22 |
+------+-----------+--------------+------+------+-------+---------------------+
```

But with the real table, with the various 'values', 'dates', texts and other information, in some 86 thousand records, this SQL does not conclude. It runs for several minutes without bringing any result, even when I use only the columns necessary for logic, as in the example created and quoted. Is there any more efficient way to approach this problem?

Comment: have you checked the logs if they show some hints that something isn't big enough like temo table .....innodb buffer.  Further give A EXPLAIN on your query. I think you are missing some Indexs on fk_1 fk:3 and parent id, then you can experimnet with combined indexes if excplain doesn't show problems.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm not the database admin, but I did get a copy. In this copy I created the indexes that affected my SQL statements and had a significant increase in performance.